# nginix always shows default welcome page

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to show my angular app on localhost:80

Here the docker-compose for the whole app (API and database are working)

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo:4.4
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        networks:
            - host
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongodb/db:/data/db
        environment:
          - MONGO_HOST= mongo
    back:
        build: Chocaponk-back
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - mongo
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - host
    front:
        build: Chocaponk-front
        ports:
            - 80:80
        networks:
            - host
networks:
    host:
        driver: bridge
```

The Dockerfile located in the front app root directory

```
FROM node:14 AS builder
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

and the nginx.conf file

```
events { }
http {
    server {
        include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried different things that could fix it but nothing worked, whenever I go to localhost I'm seeing the welcome default page of nginx, and not my app.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use [multistage-build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). In multistage-build, only the layers in last stage will be in final image, so in order to let the final image include the things you built in previous stage, you will have to explicitly copy the artifacts in previous staget to last stage.

Here, after `RUN npm run build` in `builder` stage, you did not copy anything from `builder` to final image. You may need next to make you work:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=builder /src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

NOTE: you could adjust the files/path which you want to copy to final stage. Without `COPY --from=builder`, the final image doubtless to just show the default nginx welcome page.